# Fair die rolled 20 times

Tags: probability

What is the probability that each number of 1 to 6 shows up at least once in those rolls?

My guess: 20*(6/6^20) 
20 rolls times 6 outcomes in 1 roll over total different sequences.

the 1-6 is throwing me off

Comment: Have you learned the principle of inclusion-exclusion? Consider the probability that you'll never see a 1, or that 1 and 2 both never show up, or that 1, 2, and 3 never show up...

Comment: Your solution gives that the probability goes to zero with more and more trials.  Should it become less likely to roll at least one of each number as you roll more dice?

Comment: How many dice outcomes are there where $1$ never appears?  How many where $2$ doesn't.  ...  If you take the number of all possible outcomes and delete these "something was missing" outcomes, do you get the right answer?  (No, because outcomes where both $1$ and $2$ are missing are counted twice -- need to put one copy of all "a pair is missing" back in.)  Do we get the right answer now?  (No, because we've deleted one too many of "three numbers are missing") ...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We find the probability of the complement, the probability that $1$ or more numbers are missing. We use Inclusion/Exclusion.

The probability $1$ is missing is $(5/6)^{20}$. Same for $2$ missing, and so on. But adding these up, that is, finding $\binom{6}{1}(5/6)^{20}$, counts twice the situations where $1$ and $2$ are missing.

The probability $1$ and $2$ are missing is $(4/6)^{20}$. It is the same for all the other pairs, so our second estimate for the probability at least one is missing is $\binom{6}{1}(5/6)^{20}-\binom{6}{2}(4/6)^{20}$.

But we have subtracted too much, for we have subtracted one too many time the probability that for example $1,2,3$ are all missing. So we must add back $\binom{6}{3}(3/6)^{20}$.

Thus our third estimate is $\binom{6}{1}(5/6)^{20}-\binom{6}{2}(4/6)^{20}+\binom{6}{3}(3/6)^{20}$.

Continue. Two more terms, and we will have the exact answer. But we already have a very good approximation.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In how many ways can this happen, this is the same as the number of surjections from $\{1,2,3,4,\dots,19,20\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. How many of these are there?

there are $20\brace 6$ ways to partition the domain and $6!$ ways to select which part of the domain goes to which element of the domain. Since there are $6^{20}$ possible outcomes of throwing $20$ die the final answer is

$$\dfrac{6! {20\brace 6}}{6^{20}}=\frac{2691299309615}{3173748645888}\approx0.847988$$